# Power BI - DAX question - how can I show only one result that meet the criteria from multiple row

Tags: powerbi, dax

appreciate for your help in advance.

I am building a dashboard to show the most recent shipment details

for below table, if I would like to show the last recent HOUSE on the dashboard, how can i do that and show in my visual(table)

Criteria:
if we have a Last Leg at LegCheck column, then, pick the row of "house" of the Last leg, that is the last recent "House";

if we do not have a last leg,

first, pick the row which do not have a "COB" in place

if all of the row do have a "COB" in place, pick the row has a most recent COB date

the sample raw data as below;

[image: Sample Raw Data]

| House | Master | Consol Lane | Movement Lane | GNR Origin | GNR Dest | LegCheck | ArrivalCheck | COB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 412647 | AMST2606 | AMS-CPH | JHB-STO | AMS | STO | First Leg | Not Arrived | 17-Aug-2022 |
| 412647 | CPHT0071 | CPH-STO | JHB-STO | AMS | STO | Last Leg | Not Arrived |  |
| 414467 | LHRT0639 | LHR-BRS | NGB-BHX | AMS | BHX | Transit Leg | Not Arrived, Missing Last Leg | 21-Apr-2022 |
| 414467 | AMST2518 | AMS-LHR | NGB-BHX | AMS | BHX | First Leg | Not Arrived, Missing Last Leg | 18-Apr-2022 |
| 415828 | BFST0039 | BFS-LHR | BFS-GRU | BFS | FRA | First Leg | Not Arrived | 22-Apr-2022 |
| 415828 | LHRT0640 | LHR-FRA | BFS-GRU | BFS | FRA | Transit Leg | Not Arrived, Missing Last Leg |  |

after the measurement build
I want to see a result as below;

[image: the output I want to see]

Reason:
412647 - because it is last leg (COB could null or data in there)

415828 - there are no last leg, show the one with empty COB

414467 - there are no last leg, compare the COB, choose the most recent one (21/04 vs 18/04)

Thank you every one!

Comment: Hi @Ericwhv your output will be a table. What do you plan to do with it? It seems like a filter operation with conditions(maybe if is required). The question: What you wanna see on the visual ?

Comment: The general concept is that you create a derived column that gives the record an order of relevenacy based on your rules. Then you order by this amd show just top 1

Comment: you need to revise your question, you wrote as "if we do not have a last leg" but there is a last leg on the table therefore the rest of the data (415828 & 414467)  shouldnt be in your result...

Comment: @OzanSen
Thank you for your reply, yes, the result will be a table, but it may need a DAX code to show what I need of the "HB", like the second picture i show which is the result i want to see, thank you; 
UmutK, Thank you for your help first, there is there scenarios, first, if that group of HB has a "Last Leg", then, show the "HB" that is Last Leg; Second, if there are no last leg, but "First Leg" and "Transit Leg" is containing the COB date, then pick the row which is has the most recent COB date; Third, if there are no last leg and the transit leg do not has a COB date, then, pick that.

Comment: Hi, @Ericwhv. Thank you for your explanation. Please share your data as a text so that we can copy and paste, not as an image.

Comment: @OzanSen Thank you! I put it in the question, please let me know if you need further information, sorry for the formatting, if you know how to present it better, please let me know, thank you!!

Comment: @Ericwhv Thank you! I made a couple of edit. You will have the chance to see it after they are approved by moderators. For now, Everything looks okay on my part. Please keep waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution I found, it is a bit long shoot but it works as expected...

we will create four tables (Modelling --> New Table)

First Table which contains "Last Leg"

```
Summarized First Table =
CALCULATETABLE ( 'YourTableName', ( 'YourTableName'[LegCheck ] = "Last Leg" ) )
```

Second Table with the Blank COB

```
Summarized Second Table =

VAR _house =
    DISTINCT ( 'Summarized First Table'[House ] )
RETURN
    CALCULATETABLE (
        ( 'YourTableName' ),
        NOT ( 'YourTableName'[House ] ) IN _house,
        'YourTableName'[COB] = BLANK ()
    )
```

Third Table which does not contain blank and also with the latest date.

```
Summarized Third Table =

VAR _house_first_table =
    DISTINCT ( 'Summarized First Table'[House ] )
VAR _house_second_table =
    DISTINCT ( 'Summarized Second Table'[House ] )
RETURN
    FILTER (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            ( 'YourTableName' ),
            NOT ( 'YourTableName'[House ] ) IN _house_first_table,
            NOT ( 'YourTableName'[House ] ) IN _house_second_table,
            
        ),
        'YourTableName'[COB]
            = CALCULATE (
                MAX ( 'YourTableName'[COB] ),
                ALLEXCEPT ( 'YourTableName', 'YourTableName'[House ] )
            )
    )
```

and last table is to combine them...

```
Result Table =
UNION (
    'Summarized First Table',
    'Summarized Second Table',
    'Summarized Third Table'
)
```

maybe there is another simpler way to achieve the result but this is what I can do...

please let me know if it will work on your whole dataset...

[Sample File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E7jZAJ24y0m_K4xED_fC2OzU8JCMn2Ao/view?usp=sharing)

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you, the first and second table is fine
but the third one is not work, it is saying "Argument '4' in CALCULATETABLE function is required", not sure why......

Comment: It is working on my computer. Did you install the latest power bi desktop? I will send you the working sample file tomorrow, maybe I couldn’t copy/paste correctly.

Comment: [Sample File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E7jZAJ24y0m_K4xED_fC2OzU8JCMn2Ao/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: MAke sure that you have installed the latest version of [Power Bi Desktop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58494)

Comment: @Ericwhv did it work for you ?

Comment: Thank you Umut, it is work :)
i get the meaning is the first table is just need the row with "Last Leg"
the second table is getting the data that is not in the first table, not in "last leg" and "COB" is blank
the third table is getting the data that is not in the first and second table, and the data with most recent COB, 
but may i ask you a question, what does "ALLEXCEPT" mean and how is work?

Comment: @Ericwhv I am glad it worked. Please accept as an answer ;)

'ALLEXCEPT' gives you the all data by  ignoring all other columns but not ''YourTableName'[House ]'

Comment: just done it, again, thx Umut, acutally, i am not 100% understand the logic of the third table, especailly -
        'GNR report'[COB]
            = CALCULATE (
                MAX ( 'GNR report'[COB] ),
                ALLEXCEPT ( 'GNR report', 'GNR report'[HB] )
            )
thx!

Comment: If it is working correctly with all your data, then dont mind the rest, enjoy 

Answer (score 0):

Please test this:

Note: 1 row in our result sets do not match with your expected result set.

```
Table_Filter =
UNION (
    UNION (
        CALCULATETABLE ( YourTable, YourTable[LegCheck] = "Last Leg" ),
        CALCULATETABLE (
            YourTable,
            YourTable[LegCheck] <> "Last Leg",
            YourTable[COB] = BLANK ()
        )
    ),
    CALCULATETABLE (
        YourTable,
        YourTable[LegCheck] <> "Last Leg",
        NOT ISBLANK ( YourTable[COB] ),
        LASTDATE ( YourTable[COB] )
    )
)
```

You need to select Create New table command, and paste the code above:

[image: FER]

If we test it, It returns:

[image: DSF]

Comment: check your result with the expected result... Brings House 412647 duplicated ;)

Comment: They are different, not duplicated. Only a couple of columns the same. I also used union to ensure that no duplicate rows are retrieved.

Comment: it is not the result that OP wants. you should avoid the Houses that comes with Last Leg...

Comment: You'd better read above. did you ever check carefully the expected result and it matches with your result ? 414467 ?

Comment: one clear thing is that your code doesnt give the expected result...

Comment: Thank you Ozan Sen
according to your "returns", it is not suit with my needed
same House#, we just need the one with "Last Leg", thank you